# macOS Shortcuts "Allow Running Scripts" preference keeps turning off

Tags: macos, shortcuts-app

I have a simple shortcut set up in the menu bar that runs a shell script. However, every time I run the shorcut for the first time after startup, I get a notification that the shortcut cannot be run because the action is a "scripting action" and the shortcut security setting does not allow this action to be run.

It then prompts me to check the "Allow Running Scripts" preference in the Shortcuts app preferences. This is fine, however, after quitting the Shortcuts app, the **preference seems to undo itself** and I get the same notification that the shortcut cannot run and have to re-check the checkbox in the preferences again.

Is this a bug with the Shortcuts App? Or is there something that I am doing wrong? (I am currently running macOS Monterey 12.1)

[image: Menu Bar Shorcut]

[image: Notification]

[image: Shortcuts Preferences Window]

Comment: I don't think you are doing something wrong, Shortcuts was pretty buggy when introduced (in my case, preferences like key combos got lost all the time), which is a shame, but 12.2.1 seems to have fixed quite a few of those issues. I'd recommend that you update to 12.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by jaume, this seems to be a bug with the Shortcuts app. This bug appears to be fixed as of macOS Monterey version 12.2.1

Comment: On 12.3.1 and this still happens, is there another solution?

Comment: Still happening on Ventura (13.2.1, 22D68).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug with the permissions - the preferences cannot be saved properly. See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/689436

As a workaround, try this:
Go to System Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Full Disk Access, click on |+| to add a new app, pick "Shortcuts" app and enable it.